# Which code works (with builtins) both in bash and zsh with the `time` keyword?

Tags: bash, zsh, ksh, time

It is usual to do `time cmd` for many types of `cmd`(s) in bash:

```
$ time true
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

The output format could be changed (even to a posix format with time -p):

```
$ TIMEFORMAT='real %R'; time true
real 0.000
```

But zsh doesn't report the time for simple commands (try also `time echo`):

```
% time true
```

Converting the command to a pipe reports other things:

```
$ zsh -c 'time echo yes | cat'
yes
echo yes  0.00s user 0.00s system 26% cpu 0.001 total
cat  0.00s user 0.00s system 85% cpu 0.002 total
```

The shell could be forced to give a time output with a subshell `(…)`:

```
$ zsh -c 'time ( true )'
( true; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 26% cpu 0.005 total
```

But that doesn't work with `{…}`, nor with builtins like `for`:

```
$ zsh -c 'time { for i in $(seq 100); do ls; done >/dev/null; }'
```

How could zsh's time made to accept simple commands without a subshell.

Or, an even simpler question:

**Is there a way to write code that works in ksh, bash,zsh with the time keyword?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time` does not time commands.  [From the *Single Unix Specification*'s rationale](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html#tag_20_129_18):

> The term *utility* is used, rather than *command*, to highlight the fact that shell compound commands, pipelines, special built-ins, and so on, cannot be used directly.

The *SUS* also states that the result of `time` on *special* built-in commands is undefined, and its results when used on anything other than a *simple command* (i.e. on pipelines or command groupings) are unspecified.

This is because `time` is *not* required to be special shell syntax, nor a built-in command.  And whether it was varied quite significantly at the time of first standardization, and varies significantly now.

- In the Almquist and (Heirloom) Bourne shells, `time` is neither reserved word nor built-in command.  It is an external command, and so cannot be applied to anything other than a *simple command*.  The external `time` command on the BSDs uses the process usage information returned from the kernel by the `wait4()` library function, and requires that the program being timed be a shell if you want to time shell built-in commands and pipelines.  So things like `time bindkey` do not find a utility to execute and things like `time echo` time the operation of the *external* `echo` command and not a shell built-in one.
- In the C shell, `time` is a built-in command, and cannot be applied to anything other than a *simple command*.  `time` works by looking at the results of the `wait4()` library function, which necessitates a child process to wait for.  So the C shell's `time` *always forks a child process*, even for otherwise built-in commands.  You will find that things like `time bindkey -v` achieve nothing because they are run in a child process as a consequence of `time`.
- In the Korn and Bourne Again shells, `time` is a reserved word in the shell syntax, and can be applied to pipelines.  These shells do not use the child process usage information returned by the `wait4()` library function but calculate times by bracketing invocations of commands with calls to `getrusage()`, and doing subtractions.
- In the Z shell, `time` is a reserved word in the shell syntax, and can be applied to pipelines.  The Z shell does use the process usage information returned from the kernel by the `wait4()` library function, but does not force forking for built-in commands.  So it reports nothing *when no child process has been forked* (as it the case for built-in commands such as `true`); but conversely the likes of `time set -o vi` actually achieve something.

As its rationale states, the *Single Unix Specification* is loosely worded in order to allow all of the various behaviours.  And it nods in the direction of timing shell built-in commands being a problem.

Comment: The spec say: `... pipelines ... cannot be used directly`. Both zsh and bash do apply that `reserved word` (not utility as defined in the spec) to pipelines, so they are both "out of spec" from my viewpoint.

Comment: All built-in commands become timed when in a pipeline: Try `zsh -c 'time true | read | true'`. It reports time information for both true and read, but not for the last true. Shouldn't `time { true }` work? The command is encapsulated.

Comment: I did put emphasis on "when no child process has been forked".  A pipeline forks child processes.

Comment: I would like to know why all people seem to know the so called heirloom shell, that did get only attention for half a year and that is neither fully portable nor compatible to the historic Bourne Shell. If you like a portable shell that is 100% compatible to the Bourne Shell, rather use `obosh`, which is a compile variant of `bosh`.

Answer (score -1):

While most shells support to time external and builtin commands, zsh does not support timing for builtin commands.

If you need to get a time result, you may like to call

```
time /bin/true
```

or send a bug report to the zsh people.

With the new information things look different.

Timing complex commands only works in case that `time` is a reserved word in the shell.

So you have two limiting factors

- the shell needs to be able to time builtin commands
- the shell needs to implement `time` as a reserved word that enhances the syntax of the shell

This reduces the list of potential shell candidates to:

```
bosh bash mksh ksh
```

For builtin commands, the shell needs to know how to mesure its own timing.

For complex commands, the shell needs to implement `time` inside the interpreter.

Comment: The `/bin/true` has to be loaded, started, and **then** executed. That takes some set-up time which a builtin like `true` doesn't need nor use. The times reported would be inherently different. Try `bash -c 'for cmd in true /bin/true; do time for((i=1;i<10**3;i++)); do $cmd; done; done'` (local result: real 0.016 real 1.618 .... A factor of 100).

Comment: You seem to want the timing and zsh. The other variant seems to be not to use zsh.

Comment: No, @schily I am trying my best to be shell agnostic in this question. I do prefer  bash, but I also need to measure timing of commands in zsh. So, the question remains: How to time a for loop in zsh?